# how to set asp.net web application session timeout at a fixed time....?

Tags: asp.net, session

i have googled a lot but did not find any solution regarding expiring the session of all the user logged in at a fixed time (say 12:00 AM), all i know is

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

to extend the idle time of the session.can any one help me with this

Comment: I am not sure that what you are trying to do is even doable.

The session doesn't expire at a given set time. 
Session expires once a certain amount of time has passed since the last request came, related to that session of course. 

That's the way it works so you trying to do something else which doesn't fit the way it works can be a source of all kind of strange issues. You might want to detail exactly what you are trying to accomplish and why you feel you need to do this.

Comment: there are certain codes which must execute when the user clicks the sign out button but if user dosent click the button and click the close tab button of the browser by mistake then at 12 am some code (the code which is in sign out button) will execute and expires the session of the client.my website is such that i cannot make the client session expire at any time but at 12 am i can do it for the sake of next time login.basically it calculates the time at which user uses the website